# Import express instance for integration tests

Tags: node.js, integration-testing, supertest

I did separate my unit and integration tests.

For unit test it's very simple and it's working, but I have some problem with integration tests using "supertest".

I have test commands in **packege.json**:

```
"test": "jest -c jest.config.js",
"testIntegration": "jest -c jest.config.integration.js"
```

The **jest.config.integration.js** file looks like this:

```
const unitConfig = require('./jest.config');

unitConfig.testPathIgnorePatterns = ['_tests_/unit', '_tests_/acceptance'];
unitConfig.maxConcurrency = 1;
unitConfig.globalSetup = '<rootDir>config/jest/globalSetup.js';
unitConfig.globalTeardown = '<rootDir>config/jest/globalTeardown.js';

module.exports = unitConfig;
```

The **globalSetup.js** file have one function that init db connection and init express application.

```
const startupFunctions = require('../../startupFunctions');
module.exports = (async () => {
  await startupFunctions.startup();
}), 10000;
```

Ok!
**But now, in test file, when I importing instance of express application, is pure new instance!**
Like I did const app = express()
This app have no all routes and middlewares.

if I move startup function to **beforeAll**, then everything is fine and working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found that is not possible.
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7184